# How to count the childnodes for the specific node in the XML document?

Tags: c#, xml

I'm fresher to c#. i've to parse the xml document and have to count the specific node of the childnodes.

e.g:

```
<Root>
   <Id/>
   <EmployeeList>
      <Employee>
         <Id/>
         <EmpName/>
      </Employee>
      <Employee>
         <Id/>
         <EmpName/>
      </Employee>
      <Employee>
         <Id/>
         <EmpName/>
      </Employee>
    </EmployeeList>
</Root>
```

In this xml, how do I count the "Employee" nodes??

How can i parse and get the solution using XmlDocument class in C#?

Answer (score 5):

```
int Count = doc.SelectNodes("Employee").Count;
```

Comment: is this correct??

XmlElement docEle=doc.DocumentElement;
XmlNodeList node=docEle.ChildNodes;
for(int i=0;i<node.Count;i++)
{
   if(node[i].name=="EmployeeList")
   {
      XmlNodeList emp=node[i].ChildNodes;
      int count=emp.Count;
   }
}

Answer (score 4):

You can use XPath

```
var xdoc = XDocument.Load(path_to_xml);
var employeeCount = (double)xdoc.XPathEvaluate("count(//Employee)");
```

Comment: Why casting to double not int?

Comment: @JohanLarsson it will throw `InvalidCastException`. Option here is cast to double and then to int `(int)(double)xdoc.XPathEvaluate`

Answer (score 2):

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.LoadXml(XmlString);

XmlNodeList list = doc.SelectNodes("Root/EmployeeList/Employee");
int numEmployees = list.Count;
```

if the xml is from a file, use

```
doc.Load(PathToXmlFile);
```

Answer (score 2):

Using linq to xml you can do:

```
XElement xElement = XElement.Parse(xml);
int count = xElement.Descendants("Employee").Count();
```

This assumes you have your xml in the string xml.

Answer (score 1):

I would highly recommend using the `System.Xml.Linq` library instead. it is much better than the one you are trying to use. Once you have loaded your XDocument, you can just get the root node and do something along the lines of:

```
//Parse the XML into an XDocument
int count = 0;

foreach(XElement e in RootNode.Element("EmployeeList").Elements("Employee"))
  count++;
```

This code isn't exact, but you can look here for more complex examples:
http://broadcast.oreilly.com/2010/10/understanding-c-simple-linq-to.html