# Count XML Nodes Script Task SSIS

Tags: c#, sql-server, visual-studio-2015, ssis

I have the below xml:

```
<Users>
    <User ID="User1"
         <Element1>Name1<Element1>
    </User>
    <User ID="User2"
        <Element1>Name2<Element1>
    </User>
    <User ID="User3"
        <Element1>Name3<Element1>
    </User>
</Users>
```

This XML is created and stored in a string variable in SSIS. 
I need to count the User nodes before doing the next step and I would like to do it using a script task. This what I think I need to do

```
// assign string to a variable
String XMLString = Dts.Variables["User::XMLString"].Value
// Convert variable to xml data type: 
XmlSerializer serializer = new XmlSerializer(XMLString );
//Count the user nodes and assign integer to a variable.
Dts.Variables["User::UserCount"].Value = serializer.SelectNodes("Users/User").Count;
```

I’ve been trying to figure out how to do it but I’m quite new on C# and I would really need an example about this please. 
Thanks!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17678480/how-to-count-the-childnodes-for-the-specific-node-in-the-xml-document or look up how to do this using `XPATH`

Comment: You should use `string` not `String` when defining `XMLString` variable. `string` with small `s` is a data type, the other one is a class.

Comment: thank you both for the info!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this:

```
        string XMLString = Dts.Variables["User::XMLString"].Value;
        Dts.Variables["User::UserCount"].Value = (Regex.Matches(XMLString, @"</User>")).Count;
```

See the code here in  [this link](http://rextester.com/live/ARZEI61338).

Comment: this works perfectly. I just had to add to convert the variable to string. thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
doc.Load(XMLString);
Dts.Variables["User::UserCount"].Value = doc.SelectNodes("User").Count;
```

Comment: thanks for that but the script task doesn't run succesfully. I have added the below code and it never finish once it gets to the XmlDocument: string XMLString = Dts.Variables["User::XMLString"].Value.ToString();
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.Load(XMLString);
            Dts.Variables["User::UserCount"].Value = doc.SelectNodes("User").Count;
            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;